# Compile rdlc in VS2013 - error Native compiler return value: '-1073741511'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

After installing Visual Studio 2015 I am not longer able compile my rdlc (report) file even in VS2013 - where it used to compile without error.
I getting the following error:

```
An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. 
Native compiler return value: ‘-1073741511’.
```

Through trial an error I have found that removing expressions like

> =IIf(IsNothing(First(Fields!ActualQuantity.Value, "DataSet1")),"",First(Fields!ActualQuantity.Value, "DataSet1"))

and

> ="Generated from website " + FormatDateTime(Now(),DateFormat.ShortDate)

and even

> =""

will prevent this error, while the following is fine:

> (GOOD)
>   =First(Fields!CarrierName.Value, "DataSet1")

I actually need those expressions, so hoping someone might be familiar with this problem and be able to provide guidance for tracking down a solution.

Unfortunately, other developers (and the build server) do not have a problem with compiling this report, so I'm the odd man out.

Comment: Any constructive criticism on the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was just posted on another question that might help your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33917391/5583585

> In order to resolve the RDLC build problem I had to do the following
>   (lots of digging):
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750 Resolution for scenario
>   2 Customers have to uninstall updates 3098779 and 3097997 if they have
>   upgraded their systems to the .NET Framework 4.6 or have installed
>   Visual Studio 2015 from a fully updated .NET 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 system
>   that has updates 3098779 and 3097997 installed.

Comment: Thanks for the reference Jake!! I had given up hope.