# VS 2015 Native compiler return value -1073741511 on .rdlc files when building project

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I got this error:

> rsUnexpectedCompilerError: An unexpected error occurred while
>   compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘-1073741511’

,when compiling `rdlc`'s on a new box on `Visual Studio 2015` on a `Windows 8.1` box for an existing project

This happens on **every** existing r**d**lc file in the project that **has an expression**.

I checked that. I have the latest `sql` server data tools (ssdt) installed.

I also created a brand new console application with empty report with no expressions and it compiles fine. When I add an expression to that empty report, like in the example below, it refuses to compile.

Does anyone have any idea how can I get `Visual Studio` to be able to compile `rdlcs` with expressions? The computer used to do this before it was re-imaged with `windows 8.1`.

Here's an example of a file that will not compile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>="goo"</Value>
                <Style />
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
        <Top>0.62375in</Top>
        <Left>2.88417in</Left>
        <Height>0.25in</Height>
        <Width>1in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>2in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>6.5in</Width>
  <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>931c20c8-104d-4fe3-b563-d60a1298ba59</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Here's my VS 2015 version info

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00081

Installed Version: Professional

Visual Basic 2015   XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.6
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

GenerateUnitTest   1.0
Generates unit test code for methods in classes under test.

Microsoft Azure HDInsight HQL Service   2.0.2600.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio   2.0.2600.0
An integrated development environment for HDInsight application development.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.7
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 - v2.7.30818.1601

NuGet Package Manager   3.2.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PostSharp   4.1.28.0

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50730.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to resolve the RDLC build problem I had to do the following (lots of digging):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750
Resolution for scenario 2
Customers have to uninstall updates 3098779 and 3097997 if they have upgraded their systems to the .NET Framework 4.6 or have installed Visual Studio 2015 from a fully updated .NET 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 system that has updates 3098779 and 3097997 installed.

Comment: Had this same problem and tried lots of things: recreating reports, manually editing XML, etc. Simply removed the two mentioned updates and my reports that use expressions via parameters work fine.

Comment: Now that's something I wouldn't have found and it worked perfectly... thanks!!

Comment: Removed the two updates by going to Add or Remove Programs > View installed Updates and report previews started working again.

Comment: i have the same error but a different number. and it is showing only on a few of the production machines. where did you start digging?

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the RDLC build problem I had to do the following (lots of digging):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750
Resolution for scenario 2
Customers have to uninstall updates 3098779 and 3097997 if they have upgraded their systems to the .NET Framework 4.6 or have installed Visual Studio 2015 from a fully updated .NET 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 system that has updates 3098779 and 3097997 installed.

Rebooted and it worked.

Comment: thanks for the info - i found that I have 4.6 installed due to vs 2015 being installed and once i removed 3098779 and 3097997 and rebooted looks like it is working - so those msft patches are defective or were not uninstalled as they should have been when vs 2015 installed

Answer (score 0):

Reporting Services is not available in your Visual Studio 2015 SSDT build (July 2015) as noted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) hence your issues trying to build reports

Comment: that did not fix it - installed that later october version and it still has the same issue - now my vs 2015 has these installed

SQL Server Analysis Services   13.0.700.219
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 13.0.700.219

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.51026.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 13.0.700.219

SQL Server Reporting Services   13.0.700.219
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 13.0.700.219

Answer (score 0):

We experienced this issue on one server after installing .Net 4.6 (Windows Server 2012 R2) but did not have issues on any other servers (nor on Windows 7 or Server 2008).  Some searching turned up nothing except this StackOverflow post, [Compile rdlc in VS2013 - error Native compiler return value: '-1073741511'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700016/compile-rdlc-in-vs2013-error-native-compiler-return-value-1073741511), which describes the exact issue we were having. Unfortunately it has no solution.

In our case this was a production server and we had to restore from backup to a point prior to installing .Net 4.6.

I'm working on removing the expressions from our report (which is doable in our case but may not work for you). Which so far is the only work-around we've found.

We'll be logging a bug with Microsoft and hope for a patch soon.

---

**What we tried but did not work**

- Upgrading the solution from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015
- Changing the CLR target from 4.0 to 4.6
- Upgrading Microsoft ReportViewer from v10 to v12
- Recreating the RDLC from scratch in Visual Studio 2015