# Visual studio 2015 returns a native compiler error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am having a similar issue to a thread I found on here:

[VS 2015 Native compiler return value -1073741511 on .rdlc files when building project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766585/vs-2015-native-compiler-return-value-1073741511-on-rdlc-files-when-building-pr)
 The difference is that my error is coming up on only 1 of 180 machines that my  app is installed on. My "native Compiler Code" is '-2147024770'. After Googling around for a bit, I was unable to find anything on that code number. Here is a pic of the whole error I get:

[image]

I am hoping that the guy that found the solution to the above link sees this and shares how he found the fix, so I can apply it to my error code.

Comment: Errors are ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND and STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND (from this tool http://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=1073741511+OR+2147024770 ) so there is probably a binary (dll, exe, etc.) mismatch on your machine.
I would try to repair all that. Otherwise you can also go forensics with tools like sysinternals procmon or .NET fuslogvw to check what's going on.

Comment: so the error code 1073741511 was from the example question that i referenced. i did that because it had a similar error format and someone was able to translate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier thank you for posting this link. while it isnt a solution to the problem, it gave me a way to hunt for it. if you post this as an answer, i will award you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this free tool here (Magical Number Database, I'm the author) http://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=1073741511+OR+2147024770, I found these errors are ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND and STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND.

So there is probably a binary  (dll, exe, etc.) version mismatch on your machine. First, I would try to repair the program in question. Otherwise you can use forensics tools like sysinternals [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) (and focus on the File filter) or .NET [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to check what's going on at file and binding level. There is also the standard Windows event viewer that can help.