# RDLC report randomly crashes application with compiler error -1073741502

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, rdlc, vs-web-site-project

The error as seen in the image is a compiler error -1073741502. I have searched SO and Google with little success. Tried to debug the process and was not able to determine what the issue is causing the error. The error has been occurring for some time and is random with no apparent pattern in the data or operation. This is also in a VB website using .net 4.0. The report RDLC has been recreated 2 times to see if the issue would be resolved but was not successful.

The only way to get the application to continue past this error once it occurs is to do an app pool reset. This is something we would like to avoid doing for obvious reasons.

Any help and suggestions are appreicated.[image]

Comment: This error indicate STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED. Check is there any other application accessing your IIS app pool that caused it to crash. And check if the available memory is enough.

Comment: Checked the memory and both private and virtual memory are set to 0. The list of app pool number of applications show only 1 application is running in that app pool. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would add a log function to save the data used for these report with timestamp if possible. Just the rule out this issue is not related to data.

Comment: I will try to do that but since it is an older asp vb website and using the db would not be possible for logging, may take some time to implement. However, if the report is run on several customers then throws the error, once the app pool is restarted the same customer report is run successfully. The data would be generated identical each time. Not sure how the cache is handled or other internals. Also not sure if it is a multi user multi use issue as it seems to have to compile the report RDLC each time.

Comment: That sounds weird, the report should be lost when you restart the App pool. If you mean restart and generate again, this could be the variables and session caches are lost after App pool restart, then a report with default dataset is generated.

Comment: Some other possible cause you may look into... Report generation code if they are multi-threaded, Windows Security Updates, database table locks, etc.. It's a shot in the dark really. Hope you find what you need. Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say restart and regenerate. I should have been more detailed. The application being an older web site and intranet only an application error is thrown and kills the application and the browser is closed by the user. At which point the app pool is reset and the web site is reopened and executed until the next time the exception is thrown. No pattern of how many times the report gets run successfully or data type can be found. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: Just comes to mind that you may also look into Windows Event Viewer as well. The error events should be under Windows Log > Application. You may look for Critical / Warning / Error right before the "-1073741502" Error occur. Good luck!

Comment: Seems to be the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766585/vs-2015-native-compiler-return-value-1073741511-on-rdlc-files-when-building-pr ?

Comment: @mBardos During research I had seen that post. However, this is a classic ASP (VB) site using .Net framework 4.0. Thus it does not have .Net 4.5 - 4.6 installed. Nor did it have the updates 3098779 and 3097997 installed to be removed. But thanks for suggesting it in case I had missed it. Upgrading the application isn't an option at this time due to management decisions. Fortunately, management has also decided last month to replace the application completely.

Comment: @Albert Brennan: we uninstalled the 2 updates, the issue still occurs... Me and all my colleagues, each, spent days with this, no solution yet.

Comment: @mBardos, I as well as 2 other developers have spend months off and on trying to resolve this. The only workaround I had was to run a pstools psexec command to reset IIS when ever it was reported by the users. They have decided to purchase a 3rd party vendor created application to replace the application with this issue. I will be glad to see the multiple requests a day with the error. I wish you much luck in finding the answer.